# Не могу проинициализировать FirebaseCrash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android

Добрый день. Пытаюсь использовать FirebaseCrash, создал в консоле проект, добавил зависимость в проект. Но при попытке инициализации и отправки сообщение вылетает исключение, что

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process processname. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first."
```

В MainActivity добавил следующее:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Android non-fatal error"));
```

но при выполненнии:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
```

возвращается результат NULL и Firebase не инициализируется.
Подскажите, что не так делаю? что еще необходимо настроить?

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ua.com.bioprom.biouniversal"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.5"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'ru.tinkoff.decoro:decoro:1.3.1'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all
compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '2.0.2-beta'


compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.4'

}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
     jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
   }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Покажите оба файла `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте инициализировать Firebase в классе **Application**, в методе onCreate.
Если Вы не переопределили класс Application это можно сделать следующим образом:

1. Создаёте класс наследующий Application и инициализируете Firebase

   public class App extends Application {

   ```
   @Override
   public final void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
   }
   ```
2. Прописываете этот класс в манифесте приложения в параметре "name" в блоке **application**.

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решен, нужно было добавить файл google-service.json
и прописать в build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

и

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```